# Using enum as integer for out of enum range values like in C/C++?

Tags: rust

lets say I have the following C enum:

```
enum TokenType {
    Identifier = 256,
    KeywordFunc = 257,
    KeywordReturn = 258,
    KeywordIf = 259,
    KeywordElse = 260
};
```

where the enum starts at 256 so I can use the literal ascii values of chars when I do like `TokenType type = TokenType('{');` How can I achieve something similar in Rust? I currently have:

```
pub enum TokenType {
    Identifier,
    KeywordFunc,
    KeywordReturn,
    KeywordIf,
    KeywordElse,
}

pub enum TokenTypeUnion {
    Ascii(char),
    NoneAscii(TokenType)
}
```

But maybe there's a more idiomatic solution to this?

Comment: Your C example is bad style at best, I know compilers that wont let you do this, throwing an exception at runtime if an undefined value is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just flatten the structure a little to simplify the use:

```
pub enum TokenType {
    Ascii(char),
    Identifier,
    KeywordFunc,
    KeywordReturn,
    KeywordIf,
    KeywordElse,
}

fn use_enum() {
    let token = TokenType::Ascii('}');
    let token = TokenType::Return;
}
```

Other then that I don't see any way to improve your approach, it's quite idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `From` trait like this:

```
pub enum TokenType {
    Identifier,
    KeywordFunc,
    KeywordReturn,
    KeywordIf,
    KeywordElse,
    Ascii(char),
}

impl From<TokenType> for u16 {
    fn from(tok_type: TokenType) -> u16 {
        match tok_type {
            TokenType::Identifier       => 256,
            TokenType::KeywordFunc      => 257,
            TokenType::KeywordReturn    => 258,
            TokenType::KeywordIf        => 259,
            TokenType::KeywordElse      => 260,
            TokenType::Ascii(char)      => char as u16,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", u16::from(TokenType::KeywordElse));  // 260
    println!("{}", u16::from(TokenType::Ascii('}')));   // 125
}
```